# Trigger Javascript alert from another variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code:

```
<script>
    function slboxchg()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("slbox").value != 0)
        {
            var x = 'a'+document.getElementById("slbox").value;
            alert(x);
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    var a1 = "1,2,3";
    var a2 = "3,4,5";
</script>

<select id='slbox' onchange='slboxchg()'>
    <option value='0'>None</option>
    <option value='1'>Apple</option>
    <option value='2'>Banana</option>
</select>
```

When I select "Apple", I expected the alert box show "1,2,3", but it showed "a1" instead.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: because the value of `slbox` is 1, so `'a' + 1` is `'a1'` hence thats what it alerts

Comment: @NickA I know why it showed 'a1', but I want it show '1,2,3' instead, that's why I asked.

Comment: but you didnt' ask, there isn't an actual question in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
alert(x);
```

Try:

```
alert(window[x]);
```

---

Here's a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/yXdbQK)**

Comment: Is that a cross browser thing?

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained what you were doing and why the OP's code didn't work.

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help - basically were calling `alert` on a string, which will only alert the string - you can access it instead from the `window` object. You could also create your own object and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

So what happens when we select "Apple"? The `onchange` event is called which triggers `slboxchg()` which in turn checks that the value is not 0, which is it since `1 != 0`.

The variable `x` is then defined as the string containing the letter `'a'` plus whatever is the value of the element. This value also happens to be a string, so what we actually get is `x = 'a' + '1'` which is just a string concatenation which returns `x = 'a1'`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do this a different way.

```
<script>
    var ar = ["0","1,2,3","3,4,5"];
    </script>

<script>
function slboxchg()
{
  if(document.getElementById("slbox").value != 0)
  {
    var x = ar[document.getElementById("slbox").value];
    alert(x);
  }
}
</script>



<select id='slbox' onchange='slboxchg()'>
<option value='0'>None</option>
<option value='1'>Apple</option>
<option value='2'>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This line, might be needed var x = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value; It's been a while since I used pure javascript for this. Normally use jquery